# Android for Maven Eclipse Plug-in can't be installed

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, plugins

maybe you will think this is a stupid question just for installing a plug-in.
But to be honest, I have tried 3 times to install this plug-in.

I followed this website guide: http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/
and also refer to a common asked question which is a guide to add the plug-in in stackoverflow.(but I'm sorry for not capable for posting more than 2 links because of little reputation).

Cause I'm planning to develop a new Android app, so I downloaded the "adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702" from the official website.

I can use this bundle to install m2e plug-in(adt is integrated by default as we all know).
But the problem is that I don't know why I can't install the "Android for Maven" plug-in.

By the way, cause now this adt bundle has no Marketplace Client in the Help option, I install it using "install new software".

Following is the error when I was installing the plug-in.

"
The following solutions are not available: Android for Maven Eclipse (id=com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group, site=http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/updates/)
"

When I opened the site it mentioned, "Page not found" error appeared.
I wonder whether is the author of this plug-in close the website to provide this service or not.
If they do stop the service now, please also let me know, so I can give up using it anymore.

This is the fourth time I'm asking a question in this website.(with no answer last three which is diametrically different from what I expect)
Hope any genius can give a answer this time. 
I think this may also happen to the others so they don't need to be as trouble as I am.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your eclips version?

Comment: I don't know. I just know it's the most updated one for the adt-bundle. if I choose the about Eclipse. It shows this information: Android Developer Tools

This product includes Eclipse Platform, JDT, CDT, EMF, GEF and WTP, all of which are
Copyright (c) Eclipse contributors and others.
Visit http://eclipse.org/

Android Developer Tools are Copyright (c) The Android Open Source Project.
Visit http://developer.android.com

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be some incompatibilities between the latest ADT Bundle and the m2e-android plugin, since I also couldn't get it to work.

The update URL doesn't seem to be available over a simple Browser request, but it will work under Eclipse.

For Eclipse 4.4 the developer has put out a bugfix to make it work with ADT 23, see here: https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/226

Basically point the m2e-android plugin update url to http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/updates/master/

I don't know if this will work for the ADT Bundle, but I just tried it on a clean Eclipse download with ADT and it seems to be working!

**Edit:**

Here's what I did in more details:

- Go to http://eclipse.org/ and download the latest version (It was
  Eclipse Standard 4.4, 206 MB at the time)
- In Eclipse, go to *Help* -> *Install new software...*
- Add a new site with Location *https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse*
- Select the new Location in the drop-down *Work with*
- Install the *Android Development Tools*
- Restart Eclipse

Afterwards repeat above steps starting from bullet no. 2, but add http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/updates/master/ instead of the google.com Location and install *Android for Maven Eclipse*!

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your kindly answer, but I don't know what do you mean by trying it on a clean Eclipse download with ADT, could you please give a link to download this one? Or you are saying that you just downloaded the latest Eclipse Luna and then in the Eclipse market downloaded the ADT?

Comment: Hi Clarence, sorry I was only vague about this. I'll edit my answer.